# How to fix "missing ) after argument list" error when the code in question is (seemly) non-existent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am attempting to create an audio player using the Electron framework. When I run the application I get a "missing ) after argument list" error on a line in main.js that does not exist. How can i fix this issue?

I have looked around at other forum posts, but overall i'm quite inexperienced and help would be welcome.

Console Log: Edit: managed to forget to add part of it. :P

```
 App threw an error during load
/Users/eddieb/Programming Projects/Electron/demoTesting/main.js:83
}.call(this, exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname); });
^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:660:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:704:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:602:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:533:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/eddieb/Programming Projects/Electron/demoTesting/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:119:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eddieb/Programming Projects/Electron/demoTesting/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:164:5)
```

JavaScript: (everything was fine before adding these lines.)

```
  let content = "This is the content of the audio file";
  dialog.showOpenDialog((fileNames) => {
    // fileNames is an array that contains all the selected files.
    if(fileNames === undefined){
        console.log("No file selected");
        return;
    }

    fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
            return;
        }

        // Change how to handle the file content.
        console.log("The file content is : " + data);
    });
});
```

I expected the program to boot with the file-loading functionality added, but instead I get an error in a non-existent line of code.

Comment: @DaveS no, it's not that, the final `)` balances the first `(` - the code in the question is perfectly "balanced"

Comment: what is `vm.js:79:7` - that's where the problem is

Comment: @JaromandaX: No; that's the Node.js code that parses the JS.

Comment: @SLaks - well, that's a useless error message then :p the code in the question has no issue, so the error is in code NOT in the question, and therefore the question is off topic

Comment: Is that the complete error message? There should usually be a pointer to the line that caused the problem

Comment: I'm aware, but i never created a vm.js nor could I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i entered some arguments wrong. i needed to add "}, false)".